# Multiple images are not selecting in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iPhone programming. Using below code I am displaying images in thumbnail. There we can able to select multiple images and also we can select and deselect the images. After select some images its display the selected images in next view. For that I had used another method. But problem is its displaying images in thumbnail but if I select any image means it's showing some exception. Can any body tell me how to solve this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    self.title=@"All Images";
        mImageSelected=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    mFirst=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.jpg"]];
    mFirst.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 50);

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                         initWithTarget:self 
                                         action:@selector(actionHandleTapOnImageView:)];
    mFirst.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [mFirst addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [self.view addSubview:mFirst];
    msSec=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"two.jpg"]];
    msSec.frame=CGRectMake(80, 10, 60, 50);
    UITapGestureRecognizer *secsingleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                         initWithTarget:self 
                                            action:@selector(actionHandleTapOnImageView:)];
    msSec.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [msSec addGestureRecognizer:secsingleTap];

    [self.view addSubview:msSec];
    mThird=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"three.jpg"]];
    mThird.frame=CGRectMake(150, 10, 60, 50);
    UITapGestureRecognizer *trdsingleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                            initWithTarget:self 
                                            action:@selector(actionHandleTapOnImageView:)];
    mThird.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [mThird addGestureRecognizer:trdsingleTap];

    [self.view addSubview:mThird];
    m4th=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"four.jpg"]];
    m4th.frame=CGRectMake(220, 10, 60, 50);
    UITapGestureRecognizer *frthsingleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                            initWithTarget:self 
                                             action:@selector(actionHandleTapOnImageView:)];

    m4th.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [m4th addGestureRecognizer:frthsingleTap];
    [self.view addSubview:m4th];
    m5th=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"five.jpg"]];
    m5th.frame=CGRectMake(10, 70, 60, 50);
    UITapGestureRecognizer *fifthsingleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                             initWithTarget:self 
                                              action:@selector(actionHandleTapOnImageView:)];

    m5th.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [m5th addGestureRecognizer:fifthsingleTap];
    [self.view addSubview:m5th];
    UIButton *theSshowButton=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    theSshowButton.frame=CGRectMake(100, 300, 100, 30);
    theSshowButton.layer.borderWidth=2;
    theSshowButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
    theSshowButton.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    theSshowButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [theSshowButton setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [theSshowButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [theSshowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(show) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:theSshowButton];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)actionHandleTapOnImageView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) in_ImageSenderTap
{ 
if (in_ImageSenderTap.view.tag ==0 )
  {


     mTick=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"mark.jpg"]];
     mTick.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, in_ImageSenderTap.view.frame.size.width*0.3,  in_ImageSenderTap.view.frame.size.height*0.4);

      [mImageSelected addObject:[in_ImageSenderTap.view accessibilityIdentifier]];

        [in_ImageSenderTap.view addSubview:mTick];


      in_ImageSenderTap.view.tag=1;
    }
       else
    {
    for (UIView *subviews in in_ImageSenderTap.view.subviews)
        {


            UIImageView *theSubview=(UIImageView*)subviews;

            [theSubview removeFromSuperview];
            [mImageSelected removeObjectIdenticalTo:[in_ImageSenderTap.view accessibilityIdentifier]];

        }
        in_ImageSenderTap.view.tag=0;
    }


}
```

Like this its showing some Expection.

```
2013-03-01 12:01:21.332 ImageStuf[588:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x159a012 0x12a7e7e 0x154db6a 0x154da20 0x37e0 0x4b685a 0x4b599b 0x4b70df 0x4b9d2d 0x4b9cac 0x4b1a28 0x21e972 0x21ee53 0x1fcd4a 0x1ee698 0x25fcdf9 0x25fcad0 0x150fbf5 0x150f962 0x1540bb6 0x153ff44 0x153fe1b 0x25fb7e3 0x25fb668 0x1ebffc 0x1cd2 0x1c05 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

If I comment below code in this method 
`-(void)actionHandleTapOnImageView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) in_ImageSenderTap` means its working fine but its not storing images in array.Can any body tell me how to slove this
Thanks
Aslam

```
[mImageSelected addObject:[in_ImageSenderTap.view accessibilityIdentifier]];
```

Comment: NSLog & Check [in_ImageSenderTap.view accessibilityIdentifier]. This should not be nil.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple selection you can use [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView). Such a great library and also this will work in iOS 5 as a gridView and above iOS6 it work as UICollectionView.

All the best!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why bother with inserting `accessibilityIdentifier` in the array, when you could instead add the thumbnail itself?
This will ensure you don't add `nil`, which is what is generating the crash. You're not setting `accessibilityIdentifier` on your thumbnails.

Second, why create 5 instances of `UITapGestureRecognizer`? Simply use the same instance when you `addGestureRecognizer:`, there's no need for 5 versions of it.

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to insert nil into NSArray, so it threw an exception. You should check element to be inserted.

I think you can use [ALAssetLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to select multiple images:

```
[_assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        [self.groupArray addObject:group];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Group not found!\n");
}];
```

---

```
- (void)getImages
{
    if (!self.assetsArray) {
        _assetsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    if (!self.assetsLibrary) {
        _assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    }

    @autoreleasepool {
        [self.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if (result) {
                TTAsset *ttAsset = [[TTAsset alloc] initWithAsset:result];
                [self.assetsArray addObject:ttAsset];
                [ttAsset release], ttAsset = nil;
            }
        }];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

---

After that, you can use ALAsset's thumbnail property.

[ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) is a good start point.